# Reaction of dimethyl sulfate with Protocatechualdehyde

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

I know that $\ce{(CH3)2SO4}$ reacts with phenols to give methoxybenzene. But the question that came in INChO-2018 was:

> When one equivalent of $\ce{NaOH}$ and one equivalent of dimethyl sulfate reacts with Protocatechualdehyde, **K** is formed in 87% yield. When carried out with excess of $\ce{NaOH}$ and only one equivalent of dimethyl sulfate, **M** is formed in 95% yield. Identify **K** and **M**.

How would I know that ether formation take place at *p*- to $\ce{-CHO}$ group or at *m*- to it?

This is Protocatechualdehyde

[image]

Comment: Which alkoxide is more stabilised by the -CHO group? Hint it is the one where you can delocalise the -ve charge to the -CHO

Comment: For K, think about which OH is more acidic. For M, which phenoxide is more nucleophilic.

Answer (score 4):

When one equivalent of dimethyl sulfate reacts with 3,4-dihydroxybenzaldehyde (protocatechualdehyde), there are two nucleophilic sites in the molecule, namely 3- and 4-hydroxy-groups. If one equivalent of strong base such as $\ce{NaOH}$ is used, it will deprotonate the most acetic group between them, in this case, 4-hydroxy-group. For example, $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ of 4-hydroxybenzaldehyde is $7.61$ while $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ of 3-hydroxybenzaldehyde is $8.98$ at $\pu{25 ^\circ C}$ (Ref.1). Thus, it is safe to assume that product **K** is 3-hydroxy-4-methoxybenzaldehyde (isovanillin).

However, the regioselectivity of the synthesis (when two nucleophilic sites are present) can be controlled by the number of base equivalents in this kind of alkylation steps (Ref.2). Thus, in excess $\ce{NaOH}$, both phenolic hydroxy groups of 3,4-dihydroxybenzaldehyde would be deprotonated and methylation would occur at 3-phenolate, because it is the most reactive at this point between two (basically, negative charge of 4-phenolate should be largely delocalized within aromatic nucleus with benzaldehyde group than that of 3-phenolate without direct resonance effect from benzaldehyde group).  Therefore, the major product **M** in this case would be 4-hydroxy-3-methoxybenzaldehyde (vanillin). You can probably compare with methylation of ascorbic acid in different conditions.

**Note:** Some literature mentioned that when one equivalent of $\ce{NaOH}$ is used, reaction is must faster and tends to use both methyl groups of dimethyl sulfate. Thus, I won't surprised if the given answer for **K** is 3,4-dimethoxybenzaldehyde.

**References:**

1. E. P. Serjeant, Boyd Dempsey, Editors, *IUPAC chemical data series no. 23: Ionization Constants of Organic Acids in Aqueous Solution*; Pergamon: Oxford, United Kingdom, 1979 (Values extracted from [PDF here](https://sites.chem.colostate.edu/diverdi/all_courses/CRC%20reference%20data/dissociation%20constants%20of%20organic%20acids%20and%20bases.pdf)).
2. Tobias Schneider, Vladimir Kubyshkin, Nediljko Budisa, "Synthesis of a Photo‐Caged DOPA Derivative by Selective Alkylation of 3,4‐Dihydroxybenzaldehyde," *Eur. J. Org. Chem.* **2018**, *(18)*, 2053-2063 (https://doi.org/10.1002/ejoc.201701749).

Comment: In my experience only one of the methyl groups of dimethyl sulfate (DMS) is utilized in alkylation. The formation of K involves one equivalent of NaOH and one of DMS. So K, formed in 87% yield, should be isovanillin as you argue and less likely that veratraldehyde, the dimethylated product unless there is evidence that both both methyl groups of DMS react. Otherwise, we are in agreement on K and M.